# When do I have to downcast something?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, casting

As I am new to Android. I am experiencing some difficulties regarding downcasting.

1. I have no idea when we have to downcast something. For example:

```java
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

In this case, why we have to downcast it? I received a vague answer last time saying that because it returns a view object, hence, you need to downcast it.

2. When we can use `this` for the context

```java
this.m_member = ...;
```

Would anyone mind to give some explanations (and examples) about the above questions?

Answer (score 1):

> When do I have to downcast something?

Whenever the type of the object that you get (from example, a method) isn't specific enough, and you can guarantee that the object is in fact a more specific type.

In your case, you have a method that returns a `View`, that is of *more specific type* `Button` (since [`Button` subclasses `View`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html).) You can thus cast to tell the compiler that you can guarantee a more specific type for the given object - in return you gain access to the methods that are on the more specific type you are casting to.

Comment: I would not call that downcasting. Upcasting seems more to the point. Does that exist? Never heard of both before.

Comment: @greenapps In Java land it tends to be just called "casting", and is always used when you want to assert a more specific type on an object.

Comment: That does not help me. In my land we cast the whole day. So casting was not the point. It was about down/up.

Comment: @greenapps Well, upcasting is changing to a more general type, downcasting is changing to a more specific type. Manual casts however are only needed for downcasting, since that's where things have the potential to cause problems (if I upcast a dog to a mammal, all dogs are mammals, so that will always work. However, if I downcast a mammal to a dog, not all mammals are dogs, so I could potentially end up with an invalid type.)

Comment: Sorry. That were a lot of words but you still did not react on my comment `I would not call that downcasting.`.

Comment: @greenapps Why would you not call that downcasting? Either way, that's just what it's called :-)